# why does a pass statement get executed in this if/else?

Tags: python, if-statement

When I run the following if/else in debug mode

```
if True:
  print 'here'
else:
  print 'there'
  pass  # breakpoint here
```

The debugger stops on the `pass` statement. Why is it that the `pass` statement gets executed? I know the `pass` is irrelevant, but it's inside the `else`.

I'm running python 2.7.5 on Pycharm 2.7.3

**UPDATE**

If the `pass` statement is the last line of the program, and there's a break point on it, the debugger will stop at that `pass` statement. I know it stopped because I can see the current stack trace and variables.

However if `pass` is not the last line, the debugger will not stop there.

Comment: Are you sure that the debugger doesn't stop *after*  the `pass` statement?

Answer (score 6):

The debugger doesn't break on the pass statement. You can verify this by adding a statement after it:

```
$ cat test.py
if True:
  print 'here'
else:
  print 'there'
  pass  # breakpoint here
print 'done'
$ python -m pdb test.py
> test.py(1)<module>()
-> if True:
(Pdb++) list
  1  -> if True:
  2       print 'here'
  3     else:
  4       print 'there'
  5       pass  # breakpoint here
  6     print 'done'
[EOF]
(Pdb++) break 5
Breakpoint 1 at test.py:5
(Pdb++) continue
here
done
The program finished and will be restarted
```

The debugger may *appear* to break there because it's the last line in the file?